# Can I get a family tourist visa for Taiwan?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, pakistani-citizens, taiwan, family

I am a Pakistani citizen and am married to a Taiwanese citizen. She is inviting me to visit her for a month; can I get a Taiwan family visit visa for a month with single entry?

What documents do I need to prepare and from which country can I apply for a visit visa?

Comment: Well junaid from your name looks like you are a male and married to a Taiwanese lady. Where you and your wife live? In which country you are residing?